# Proving the Ideal Generated by the Coefficients of $f(X)\cdot g(X)\in R[X]$ is $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $f(X),g(X)\in R[X]$. Assume the ideals generated by the coefficients of $f(X),g(X)$ are both $R$. Prove that the ideal generated by the coefficients of the product $f(X)g(X)$ is also $R$.

Let $$f(X)=a_nx^n+\cdots +a_0, \\g(X)=b_nx^n+\cdots + b_0$$ (I am not assuming that they have the same degree - $a_n$ or $b_n$ can be $0$). We are given $$(a_n,\ldots,a_0)=(b_n\ldots, b_0)=R$$ Now $$f(X)g(X)=\sum_{i=0}^n\Bigg(\sum_{j+k=i}a_jb_k\Bigg)x^i$$ so the ideal generated by the coefficients is $I=(a_0b_0, a_1b_0+a_0b_1,\ldots, \sum_{j+k=n}a_jb_k)$. **How can one show $I=R$?** My only strategy (**Update 1:** Thomas' answer shows this is incorrect) is that  $I=R$ because $$I=Ra_0b_0+R(a_1b_0+a_0b_1)+\cdots + R\sum_{j+k=n}a_jb_k\\=Ra_0+Ra_1+\cdots + Ra_n\\=R+R+\cdots +R\\=R$$ where in the 3rd expression I am distributing the $R$ through each sum and using the fact that $Rt=R$ for any $t\in R$.

**Update 2:** Since $(a_1,\ldots, a_n)=(b_1,\ldots, b_n)=R$, there exists $r_0,\ldots , r_n, r_0',\ldots, r_n'\in R$ such that $r_0a_0+\cdots r_na_n =1,  r_0'b_0+\cdots + r_n'b_n=1$, so multiplying these two equations gives $$r_0r_0'a_0b_0 + r_0r_1'a_0b_1 + r_1r_0'a_1b_0 + \cdots=1 \tag{$*$}$$ 
but the left hand side isn't an element of $I$ since $a_1b_0 + a_0b_1$ have distinct coefficients in $(*)$. I am unsure if this can be modified.

Comment: Hmm, you put a question mark after your answer, but still, where is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $f = a_0 + ... + a_mX^m$ and $g = b_0 + ... + b_nX^n$.  It suffices to show that for each maximal ideal $M$, there is a coefficient of $fg$ not in $M$.  Let $k$ and $l$ be minimal with $a_k,b_l \notin M$. Check that the coefficient of $X^{k+l}$ is not in $M$.

Comment: what if no such $k,l$ exists?

Comment: They must exist since $(a_0,\ldots,a_m) = (b_0,\ldots,b_n) = R$ is not contained in any proper ideal.  Edit:  Also, I gave only a rough outline so that you can figure out the rest yourself now that you know the starting point, but I can fill in a complete solution if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

No, this argument fails at the point where $Ra_0b_0$ is replaced by $Ra_0$.  In general $Ra_0$ is larger than $Ra_0b_0$.  In particular, your claim $Rt = R$ is wrong, since $Rt$ is the ideal generated by $t$ in $R$.